# How install font-awesome via bower

Tags: bower, font-awesome

I have just installed font-awesome via bower:

```
bower install font-awesome --save
```

And it appears to not add the CSS at the bower build.
How can I install it?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When you use font-awesome via bower it does not include the CSS when you build it. Try using:

```
bower install components-font-awesome --save
```

It should work just fine.

Comment: why are the CSS files not minified?

Comment: What is the proper css file to link? it seems that my FA unicode is not working on my end.

Answer (score 9):

In bower.json, add lines in dependencies ("components-font-awesome"):

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": ">=3.3.0",
    "components-font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
  }
}
```

Run bower install, You will get files in the bower_components folder.

Comment: jquery and bootstrap-sass-official are not necessary.

Comment: This answer is an easier and provides more control over the font awesome version. And the comment about not needing jquery and bootstrap is correct.

Answer (score 0):

- **bower install components-font-awesome --save**
  Use this command to install font-awesome via bower.
- If the above command doesn't work that is it does not include the CSS when you build it.
  Try using the following commands.
- **bower install components-font-awesome --save**
- **bower install font-awesome --save**

Answer (score 0):

check the latest or specific version of font awesome you want to install form following link
https://libraries.io/bower/Font-Awesome/tags?page=1

current latest version of fontaswesome is 5.15.3

https://libraries.io/bower/Font-Awesome/5.15.3

```
bower install Font-Awesome#5.15.3
```

people also like version  4  as well

https://libraries.io/bower/Font-Awesome/v4.7.0

```
bower install Font-Awesome#v4.7.0
```

Answer (score -5):

This should be following command:

```
 bower install fontawesome --save
```